# Can I automatically prompt a user to add a mobile web app to their homescreen? [iOS]

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone, html, css

Can I automatically prompt a user to add a mobile web app to their homescreen? (iOS)

Is there an equivalent on Android?

Thanks very much!

Comment: Very unclear what you're asking - from what context would you ask the user to do this?  What app would you ask them about?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On iOS, the best you can do is point an arrow at the bottom (middle) of the screen and tell them to add it to thier home screen.

Comment: Is there anyway to only allow access after this action has been taken? Any way to detect if the client has added the app to their homescreen in the header information?

Comment: Found the answer to this I think, use `if (window.navigator.standalone == true)`